# Deputy badge after a reputation of 3000

Tags: support, reputation, badges, privileges

I will reach a score of **3000** in coming days in stackoverflow. In **privileges** section, for 3000, I have seen;

> Note that once you gain the reputation to vote to close, you should no longer flag for moderator attention to have questions closed or migrated. It is your responsibility to vote now.

In badges info, it is noted that the requirement of **Deputy** silver badge is **raising 80 helpful flags**. How can I track (or how to achieve) this badge after reaching a reputation level of 3000?

Comment: There are a lot of non-answers everyday, which is enough to get you to 80 flags in less than 1 week.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some scenarios where you can (and should) still flag to moderators rather than voting to close, and those flags will of course count towards the Deputy badge. For example, if a question is blatant spam; or contains blatantly offensive or abusive content. And you can always choose the "other" radio button and send a custom flag to a moderator.

[image: Flag UI once north of 3000 rep]

That said, you should be making use of close votes now for the scenarios they're designed to handle rather than flagging moderators just to maintain you progress towards the Deputy badge.

Answer (score 6):

You can see the number of helpful flags on your profile. That way you can track your progress towards the deputy badge.

You can still flag for other reasons. And you can flag to close if you run out of close votes.

But if you like it the "old" way, you can always put a 500 rep bounty on a question in order to drop below 3000 reputation.

Answer (score 4):

On your profile, there's a section on the right with the title 'helpful flags', check it. Also, flags can be raised for rude comments, non-answers and low quality questions (**along** with voting for closure).